# grunt-contrib-connect not serving files from my specified base

Tags: gruntjs

I have a very simple configuration for grunt-contribu-connect in my Gruntfile.

```
connect: {
  dev: {
    base: 'dist'
  }
},
```

The task runs and is kept alive by my watch task, but, whenever I try to open a page from this base directory, I get error output instead of the desired page.

```
Cannot GET /odds.html
```

In this image, you can see my project structure. The Gruntfile is at the project base, and the `odds.html` file I want to open is in the `dist` folder relative to that.

[image: Project folder and file structure]

Here, you can see the error along with the URI I'm trying to hit.

[image: Browser with the error message]

I'm sure I'm overlooking something silly, but I cannot see it. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you specified the port in the Grunt configuration? E.g. `dev: { base: 'dist', options: { port: 8000 } }`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I have not. I'm using the default port of 8000. The server seems to be working as the error I'm getting is a server error. I'm not getting a Chrome error as if I'm not even hitting a local server at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that you need to add 'options' and/or 'keepalive' as follows.

```
connect: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      base: 'dist',
      keepalive: true
    }
  }
},
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you. I had forgotten to put the base inside options for the task configuration.